# Getting started with effeckt.css - understanding the documentation?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'd like to use some of the [effects provided with Effeckt.css](http://h5bp.github.io/Effeckt.css/dist/) - buttons and off-screen nav. [Looking at the source](https://github.com/h5bp/Effeckt.css), I can see it's been neatly arranged to be modular.

I have cloned the project, but I don't really know how to get started as a user - the docs seem to be aimed at contributors.

Say I just want to include a button. I've tried copying the `demo.autoprefixed.css` and `effeckt.autoprefixed.css` files to my own project, and then done this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/m.autoprefixed.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/effeckt.autoprefixed.css">
  ...
  <div class="button-demo-wrap">
    <button class="effeckt-button slide-left"><span class="label">Slide Left</span> <span class="spinner"></span></button>
  </div>
```

This doesn't work, and it includes an awful lot of code I don't need for just one button. How do I get started with this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have to do with JavaScript.

I inspected the site, and it seems Effeckt.css is an CSS-Framework which needs a bit of Javascript to trigger the animations.
The following code (which is also in the JS-Fiddle) was found in the buttons.js which is referenced on their demo-site.

I have made a sample demo on how to use these buttons here:
http://jsfiddle.net/fc6ux/

The relevant part is following:

```
$('.effeckt-button').on( 'click', function(){
    showLoader(this);
});

function showLoader(el) {
    var button = $(el),
        resetTimeout;

    if(button.attr( 'data-loading' )){
        button.removeAttr( 'data-loading' );
    } 
    else {
        button.attr( 'data-loading', true );
    }

    clearTimeout( resetTimeout );
    resetTimeout = setTimeout( function() {
        button.removeAttr( 'data-loading' );
    }, 2000 );
}
```